# проблема в работе jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

всем привет. Подключил jQuery к HTML, но ничего не работает, когда добавляю $ или jQuery. Для проверки написал alert('привет'); - оно работает. 
Я прикрепил коды, и по логике, так всё должно работать. Но на страничке не появляется ссылка "перейти в гугл". Без понятия, как это исправить.

```js
$('Document').ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<a href="google.com">перейти в гугл</a>');
});
```

```css
body {
    background: url("Glavnaya-kartinka-15.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Rin&Newt</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devise-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link  rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" crs="jQuery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<center><b><h1>ВКОНТАКТЕ</h1></b></center>
 <div class="group-1">
  <ul class="full-width">
     <li><a href="index2.html" ><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>профиль</a>
     <li><a href="friends.html">друзья</a>
     <li><a href="">сообщения</a>
     <li><a href="">группы</a>
     <li><a href="https://vk.com/games">игры</a>
     <li><a href="index.html">понравилось</a>
      <div id="test" onlick="$('test').hide ()">test</div>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">$('Document').ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<a href="google.com">перейти в гугл</a>');
});</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script ... crs=` => `src=`

Comment: $('Document') -  напиши с маленькой

Comment: Документ не нужно обрамлять в кавычки и писать с больших букв `document` - это же объект `window.document`.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rin&Newt</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devise-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        background: url("Glavnaya-kartinka-15.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
<body>
<center><b><h1>ВКОНТАКТЕ</h1></b></center>
<div class="group-1">
    <ul class="full-width">
        <li><a href="index2.html" ><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>профиль</a>
        <li><a href="friends.html">друзья</a>
        <li><a href="">сообщения</a>
        <li><a href="">группы</a>
        <li><a href="https://vk.com/games">игры</a>
        <li><a href="index.html">понравилось</a>
            <div id="test" onlick="$('test').hide ()">test</div>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').append('<a href="google.com">перейти в гугл</a>');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```